# Is there a way to bind keys or key combinations to paste prespecified text in Windows?

Tags: windows, macros, keyboard

I and finding myself rewriting the same function over and over (scss mixin), and it would be nice if I could press the cnt + shift + ANYTHING to paste it, irrespective of what's in my clipboard - and not affecting the contents of the clipboard.

I am using the Microsoft Ergo 4000 keyboard and it has mappable keys, that only map to open applications and are not configurable.

My attempt to search for a solution provided me a million solutions to pasting using macros in excel.